# Will HTML5 app.manifest work with MVC style URLS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

Given the following example manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1 2011-08-14
# This is another comment
index.html
cache.html
http://somedomain.com/abc/xyz/
/style/css
controller/view/1

# Use from network if available
NETWORK:
/api

# Fallback content
FALLBACK:
/ fallback.html
```

Will "/style/css" and "/controller/view/1" work, or does it require actual file names?  I keep reading about putting "files" there, but on other sites I read "URI".  I'm assuming URI is correct.  So, are full AND relative URIs allowed? Any cross-browser/device issues to be aware of?

BTW 1: Yes, I'm aware that "file names" are just part of a URI, and names don't dictate content (image.png could download a text file, for example, if one wanted to).   I only want to confirm that URIs work well in the CACHE MANIFEST section, thanks.

BTW 2: I'm aware that Mozilla states URI for the cache manifest, so as mentioned, I just want to confirm.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic manifest file which is actually designed to work with MVC. I've not had chance to use it myself but it looks really good!

http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/mvc-and-the-html5-application-cache/59